# google analytics custom plugin getting error invalid grant

Tags: google-analytics, oauth-2.0, wordpress, google-api-php-client

```
$client = new Google_Client();
            $client->setAuthConfigFile(plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/client_secrets.json');
            $client->setRedirectUri('urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob');
            $client->addScope(Google_Service_Analytics::ANALYTICS_READONLY);
            $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);
            $client->setAccessType('offline');
            $client->revokeToken();
            $auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
```

using a popup authentication with javascript and then

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['access_token'])) {
        //$client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
      
        if($client->isAccessTokenExpired()){
            $client->authenticate($this->options['authenication_code']);
            
            $refreshToken = $client->getRefreshToken();
            $client->refreshToken( $refreshToken );
            $accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
        }
        $_SESSION['access_token'] = $accessToken ? $accessToken : $refreshToken;
    }
```

After authenticating It is giving the result ,but while using another session to  get the data it is showing errors different error in different circumstances no clear idea

> Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access
> token, message: 'invalid_grant: Invalid code.'
>
> Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access
> token, message: 'invalid_grant' *if checked after some time*
>
> Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2 access
> token, message: 'invalid_grant: Code was already redeemed.' *authenticated closed the browser and try with another browser*

This is my 4th week on this but still unable to get things correctly.

I have gone through certain posts but no luck

1.[Unable to refresh OAuth2 token in PHP, invalid grant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848002/unable-to-refresh-oauth2-token-in-php-invalid-grant)

2.[authenticate() accepts invalid tokens](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/issues/398)

3.[Getting "invalid_grant" error on token refresh](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/issues/detail?id=90)

4.[Problem in refreshing access token](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/issues/detail?id=94)

5.[Why do I keep catching a Google_Auth_Exception for invalid_grant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23498104/why-do-i-keep-catching-a-google-auth-exception-for-invalid-grant)

6.[How to refresh token with Google API client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9241213/how-to-refresh-token-with-google-api-client)

7.[Google OAuth2 - access token & refresh token -> invalid_grant/Code was already redeemed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058806/google-oauth2-access-token-refresh-token-invalid-grant-code-was-already-r)

8.[Use OAuth Refresh Token to Obtain New Access Token - Google API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23880928/use-oauth-refresh-token-to-obtain-new-access-token-google-api)

9.[Using refresh_token for Google OAuth 2.0 returns http 400 bad request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820302/using-refresh-token-for-google-oauth-2-0-returns-http-400-bad-request)

and some more if I need to post more codes or anything else please let me know.

[full code](https://gist.github.com/PrafullaKumarSahu/e5c4facbe6431bf55753)

Comment: $google_token= json_decode($_SESSION['access_token']); is just going to give you a decoded (Why you would want to ) access token.  $google_token->refresh_token  <-- wont do anything print it.   Access token does not contain refreshtoken.

Comment: @DaImTo than you for your response , Is there any function to get refresh token after authentication ?

Comment: $client->getRefreshToken();

Comment: @DaImTo I have again updated my code can you please check it.

Comment: @DaImTo I have posted a link to my total code on gistgithub  can you please check it.

Comment: People coming here can consider visiting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33676432/not-getting-correct-redirect-uri-for-google-analytics-installedappcustom-plugin and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870439/how-to-use-refresh-token-to-get-authorized-in-background-and-getting-access-toke